# How to change the font-family for Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ee

I recently upgraded my self-hosted GitLab-ee from 15.7.5 to 16.8.1, and I got an issue with the Arabic font in the gitlab web UI.

Is there any way to edit the font used?

[image]